# ASP.Net IIS location path authorization issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication

I have a website that uses forms authentication with an image on the master page that will not display when published to the host web server, however it will display when hosted on my local machine.  The site is using ASP.Net web forms on the 4.0 framework and both environments are using IIS 7.  Does anyone know why this will not work when published out to the server?  If I go to http://serverwebsiteaddr/images/logo_myworkplace.jpg on the server it redirects me to the login page, but the image correctly displays if I go to the analogous url on my dev box http://devmachinenameaddr/images/logo_myworkplace.jpg

Here is my configuration file:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<location path="images/logo_myworkplace.jpg">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users ="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Server Configuration: IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2,
Dev Box:  IIS 7.5, Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: Could it be directory permissions?

Comment: I checked and IIS_IUSRS has read rights on both systems to the directories.  Is there a server setting somewhere that would cause IIS to ignore the location path config setting?

Comment: Try using an absolute URL in the path i.e. /images/logo_myworkplace.jpg

Comment: I tried that and just path="images", no luck.  Something on that server is causing everything in the site to require forms auth and completely ignoring the location path settings.

Comment: I added read rights to the Users group on the images folder server and it all works now.  Thanks @tomasmcguinness, it turns out it was the directory permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Add a web.config file to your images directory and put the following in it.  Essentially you want to turn off authentication for that directory.  This is untested, btw.  Not sure if it will work.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I created the web.config in the images directory, but was still redirected to the login page if I tried to access it prior to logging in.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a passthrough setting on IIS that routes all files through the .NET HttpHandler.  This is useful for protecting members only content for everything in a directory.  If the HttpHandler is enabled for JPG files, it will first run the authentication rules from the web.config before delivering the file.  Your local box may not have that set up.

Comment: I checked and didn't see any handlers for JPG files.  To verify I created a default.html page in the images folder and was still unable to view that page on the server after I updated the web config to <location path="images">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users ="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web

Comment: What about wildcard settings?  It seems that IIS is serving up the authentication rules before processing a file.

Answer (score 0):

While the top folder has specific authorization to protect its files, I could set another authorization for its subfolder, with an inner web.config. So I can see .aspx pages on this subfolder without problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <identity impersonate="true" />
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark:

Could it be that the images subfolder is mapped to another app pool that is not in integrated mode ?